# Using Physics vs Rigid body Animation

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'm having an absolute fail at the moment.

I'm trying to do a very simple golf club swinging and hitting a golf ball. Before proper modelling I was experimenting with bits and bobs and failed miserably.

I'm thinking that the golf club will essentially be a cube for the head and cylinder for the shaft. Then joined together.  For now, i would like the golf club to then rotate around top surface of the cylinder/shaft and as it comes down the "cube" hits the ball...

1. I thought i could do physics with club as active element with rigid body contstrained to an empty on the top surface to cylinder/shaft. I.e. the club would fall but teh top of the shaft would be fixed...  However, every combination i have done results in whole club just fallling down.
2. I could animate it with start position and finish position of club but feel it wouldn't give real dynamics as well..

First of all, does anyone know why my physics wasn't working and it was all dropping down.

DOes anyone have opinions on when to use the phyics rigid body vs animations..

Thanks
Richard

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a screenshot of your settings?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out you needed an empty  and a separate object to "link it to"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)